# At least two participants in a meeting received the same number of phone numbers

Tags: graph-theory

The question is: there are $n$ participants in a meeting ($n \geq 2$). During this meeting, people exchanged phone numbers with each other. Prove that at least $2$ participants received the same number of phone numbers.

I was thinking of solving it using contradiction. So somehow prove that at least $2$ participants doesn't receive the same number of phone numbers, or no one received the same number of phone numbers. Would that work?

Comment: Hint: Pigeonhole principle.

Comment: You have to assume "exchange" means that if person A gets person B's number then person B gets person A's number - that it, it really is a pairwise swap. You also have to assume that each person only shares one number - that is, I don't give my home and work phone number to people.)

Comment: Yes each person only shares 1 number, and if A shares with B, then B shares with A, thus exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many numbers can a person get? Anywhere from $0$ to $n-1$ numbers.

If they all get a different number of numbers, then somebody must get $0$ numbers and somebody must get $n-1$ numbers. (Why?) Is that possible?